# Magento2 Display extra product image in product page

Tags: magento2, product-images

I would like to display more related products of a product in my Magento 2 product page. with the following code, I can successfully get part of the path of a product image.

```
$related_products = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => substr($_product->getSku(),0,8) .'%'))
                   ->addFieldToFilter('type_id','configurable');

foreach($replated_products as $relatedproduct){
   echo $relatedproduct->getImage();
}
```

this code will output something like **/2/0/2050-101-9884.jpg**, But how can I display it as a image? I haven't been able to find out how to get the full image path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use full image URL as below.

```
$store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
...
$imageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $relatedproduct->getImage();
```

To get thumbnail URL

```
$imagewidth=200;
$imageheight=200;
$imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$image_url = $imageHelper->init($relatedproduct, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($relatedproduct->getFile())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl();
```

Comment: Great, I got it. What if I want to get the thumbnail image of a product?

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your awanwer because it helped my question. But regarding the thumbnail image, your code got me this path Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg, just a placeholder. I couldn't get the actual thumbnail of the product.

Comment: Did you set thumbnail image for those products ?

Comment: I did set a thumbnail image. So far I used your first method to get the product image, and then resized it by width and height attributes in ima tag.  I think it's ok for now

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$productHelper = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product')
foreach($replated_products as $relatedproduct){
   $thumbnailUrl = $productHelper->getThumbnailUrl(relatedproduct)
   $imageUrl = $productHelper->getImageUrl(relatedproduct)
   $smallImageUrl = $productHelper->getSmallImageUrl(relatedproduct)
}
```

Comment: It got me this one, Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg. A placeholder but not the actual image of the product.